# Why the name attribute for ui:insert is optional but mandatory for ui:define?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, templating

As fas as I understood, `ui:define` is used in files acting as template clients and `ui:insert` is used in files acting as master templates of Facelets technology go hand in hand and the linkage between the two happens through the "name" attribute. But I see that the "name" attribute is **optional** for `ui:insert` but **mandatory** for `ui:define`. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<ui:insert/>` can also be used in tag files to insert tag body content.

E.g.

`/WEB-INF/tags/someTag.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <p>Some HTML ...</p>
    <ui:insert/>
    <p>Some other HTML...</p>
<ui:composition>
```

which is to be used as

```
<my:someTag ...>
    <p>This content will end up in place of ui:insert.</p>
</my:someTag>
```

---

This is particularly useful for datatables by the way:

`/WEB-INF/tags/dataTable.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <h:dataTable ...>
        <ui:insert/>
    </h:dataTable>
<ui:composition>
```

which is to be used as

```
<my:dataTable ...>
    <h:column>...</h:column> <!-- can also be another tag file! -->
</my:dataTable>
```

Note that the above isn't possible with composite components.

#### See also:

- [How to create a composite component for a datatable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439886/how-to-create-a-composite-component-for-a-datatable-column)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)