# Extend primefaces column and add a custom boolean attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to extend primefaces column and add a custom boolean attribute. I created custom component extending the primefaces column component.

```
public class TColumn extends Column {
    private enum PropertyKeys {
        tickable
    }
    public boolean isTickable() {
        return (java.lang.Boolean) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.tickable, false);
    }
    public void setTickable(boolean _tickable) {
        getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.tickable, _tickable);
    }
}
```

Is this sufficient or do I have to extend datatable renderer as well? Thanks.

Comment: tried the above, getting this exception, Any suggestions or alternate approach? Thanks. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID  already been found in the view.  
 at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness

Comment: I think the ColumnHandler is rendering the custom column twice causing the duplicate id issue. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I think post explains some valid points...please respond if there are any other suggestions. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439886/how-to-create-a-composite-component-for-a-datatable-column