# JSF: How to insert something into a custom facelets tag?

Tags: jsf

I have created a custom facelets tag file, but I'm struggeling to insert something into it. This is the tag:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h1>TestTag</h1>
  <ui:insert name="foo"/>
</ui:composition>
```

This is how I expect to use it:

```
<ds:testtag>
  <ui:define name="foo">
    <h2>TestInsert</h2>
  </ui:define>
</ds:testtag>
```

Of course, I have created a taglib file and registered it in web.xml. The ds: namespace is also declared in the file where I want to use the tag.

On the rendered result I can see the **TestTag** caption from the tag itself, but not the inserted **TestInsert**.

The answer to this question [How to create a custom Facelets tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag) as well as a comment here [How to create a composite component for a datatable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439886/how-to-create-a-composite-component-for-a-datatable-column) suggests that it is possible to insert something into a tag; unfortunately, I couldn't find a working example. What am I missing?

Comment: I have tags with named inserts and it works. I means using ui:insert with name in tag file and ui:define with name in client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h1>TestTag</h1>
  <ui:insert />
</ui:composition>
```

And use component like this:

```
<ds:testtag>
    <h2>TestInsert</h2>
</ds:testtag>
```

Answer (score -3):

You need insert into component a tag:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h1>TestTag</h1>
  <ui:insertChildren/>
</ui:composition>
```

And when use it like this:

```
<ds:testtag>
    <h2>TestInsert</h2>
</ds:testtag>
```

Also you may use

```
<composite:insertChildren/>
```

Don't forget for right imports

```
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
```

or

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
```