# How to include a primeface column into a composite

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I have a primefaces datatable with a lot of similar columns such as

```
    <p:column filterBy="#{element.value}" filterFunction="#{applicationHelperController.filterByNumber}" styleClass="ps-90-header" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:tooltip for="@next" value="Some header tooltip"/>
            <h:outputText id="#{header}_id" value="Some header" styleClass="ps-90-header" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{element.value}" />
    </p:column>
```

Is there a way of creating a composite for it such as to write

```
<mine:column value="#{element.value}" header="Some header" headerTooltip="Some header tooltip" />
```

I've been searching/trying things for a day now without any real success.
I've managed to use an `<ui:include...>` with params but it's almost as verbose as the original

```
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/countColumn.xhtml" >
        <ui:param name="value" value="#{element.value}"/>
        <ui:param name="header" value="Some header"/>
        <ui:param name="headerTooltip" value="Some header tooltip"/>
    </ui:include>
```

I've tried using taglib as preconized here [How to create a composite component for a datatable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439886/how-to-create-a-composite-component-for-a-datatable-column/11444365#11444365) even if it uses richfaces and this solution [Column as Composite Component inside DataTable](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=8610) but none work.

I've also read somewhere that `<p:column...>` should be a direct child of `<p:datatable...>` so it is not possible but I believe that was with old primefaces version (3 or 4).

So, does anyone know if it is possible with Primefaces 6 or 8 and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom Facelet tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag) to DRY your code.

Simply create tags for columns like:

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <p:column ...>
    ...
  </p:column>
</ui:composition>
```

This is how a table looks in one of our projects:

```html
<dt:dataTable controller="#{controller}"
              sortField="activationDate">
  <dt:column id="id"/>
  <dt:columnDate id="activationDate"/>
  ...
<dt:dataTable/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasper, this did the trick... well almost. I got my columns to display and all but I'm using a custom filter function with the filterFunction attribute and only the last column filters correctly. The other just dont filter anything (they seem to be ignored). Works fine when I use explicit p:column tags though. Any idea why? I guess I should really create a new thread for this problem!

Comment: No idea.. we use custom filtering. Maybe add a new question and add some details.